"Erase not allowed on the locked phone" when trying to flash or reset my itel A58
I'm trying to flash or reset my itel A58. I tried to reset the phone using adb fastboot erase userdata, but I got "Erase not allowed on the locked phone" problem.
How do I solve it?

You should describe in detail what you are trying to do. Just mentioning something like "adb-fastboot-erase-userdata" which nobody understands isn't enough.

Is there a reason you cant unlock it?
